# VMware - Broadcom 1000Gbps NIC does not link at 100Mbps to a Cisco switch port

Tags: networking, vmware-esx, linux-networking, broadcom

Today we've stumbled on a very awkward situation with our VMWare Server.
The server is with ESX 3.5 that has a 1Gbps NIC.

We bought a brand new managed Cisco Linksys switch with 10/100Mbps interface ports but when we plugged the cable in one of the ports the link simply does not wanted to activate :S...

Does anyone with more VMware experience have ever had similar problem? From what I know is that 1Gbps NICs are backwards compatible with 100Mbps switches.

This is what we've tryed so far but with no success:

1. Tryed: http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1004089
2. Tryed to modify the `/etc/modules.conf` folowing the guide from this article
   http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=813
3. After the changes I have restarted the networking services using `# service network restart`, `# service mgmt-vmware restart` and `# service vmware-vpxa restart`

It seems that no matter how many times, or whatever approach/method (GUI or Shell) we try to change the speed and duplex of the network adapter and to force it to 100mbps it only accepts 1Gbps ..

I am starting to go nuts :@

Comment: What NIC does the server have?

Comment: Is there an actual networking problem yet? You didn't specify that the server is not routable, etc etc.

Comment: Does it work on another port or another switch?  If so the port or switch is the problem.  If not, the NIC is the problem.

Comment: Is it a HP Blade? if so then they do sometimes use 1Gig-only cards, I know they're made by broadcom so maybe they have their own-branded version. Best just check on their site to see if you've bought a 1Gig-only card really.

Comment: @Chopper3 | Yes.. it is a HP Blade... i've just read on other forums that broadcom made 1gig only cards! FFS I can't believe that a company can be that stupid and create network cards that are not backwards compatible!

Comment: @Joel | What do you mean with `Is there an actual networking problem yet`? The server worked fine with the previous switch.. It was a 1Gbps  switch but was only 8 port so we needed another solution...

Comment: I am not giving up hopes... perhaps I should start a bounty on this one... 2 days left :)

Comment: By which I mean, can you perform the typical tasks of managing and hosting VMs, regardless of the "negotiated" speed?

Comment: On the "switch" itself have you nailed down the speed and duplex?

Comment: @OviBorrero | Yes.. I tried experimenting with the speed and duplex on both sides the switch and the server.. I even tried with other devices on my network just to see the impact... the netowk adapter on the VMware server is always set on 1000Mbps Auto/Negotiate no matter the option I choose speed, duplex, adapter's driver or else :S

Comment: ethtool -s vmnic0 speed 100 duplex full > have you tried running that from the console of the esx server?